# Can I use dungeon keys in the nexus?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

In the past in [Realm of the Mad God](http://www.realmofthemadgod.com), one was able to collect keys from defeated Gods that would open dungeons, bring these keys to the nexus, open the dungeon and flood it with the crowd in the nexus. This ability to collect keys from defeated Gods was axed, but now I see the ability to buy these dungeon keys. Before I buy a key, I'd like to know if it can be used in the nexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw 4 pirate caves in the nexus the other day, so I conclude that yes, it is possible to use a dungeon key in the nexus.

Comment: You can also use them in your vault... if you want to solo one.